# DirectX 11: text output, using your own font texture

Tags: text, directx, sprite, textures, directx-11

I'm learning DirectX, using the book "Sherrod A., Jones W. - Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming - 2011" Now I'm exploring the 4th chapter about drawing text.

Please, help we to fix my function, that I'm using to draw a string on the screen. I've already loaded font texture and in the function I create some sprites with letters and define texture coordinates for them. This compiles correctly, but doesn't draw anything. What's wrong?

```
bool DirectXSpriteGame :: DrawString(char* StringToDraw, float StartX, float StartY)
{
//VAR
    HRESULT D3DResult;                                                                              //The result of D3D functions

    int i;                                                                                          //Counters
    const int IndexA = static_cast<char>('A');                                                      //ASCII index of letter A
    const int IndexZ = static_cast<char>('Z');                                                      //ASCII index of letter Z
    int StringLenth = strlen(StringToDraw);                                                         //Lenth of drawing string
    float ScreenCharWidth = static_cast<float>(LETTER_WIDTH) / static_cast<float>(SCREEN_WIDTH);    //Width of the single char on the screen(in %)
    float ScreenCharHeight = static_cast<float>(LETTER_HEIGHT) / static_cast<float>(SCREEN_HEIGHT); //Height of the single char on the screen(in %)
    float TexelCharWidth = 1.0f / static_cast<float>(LETTERS_NUM);                                  //Width of the char texel(in the texture %)
    float ThisStartX;                                                                               //The start x of the current letter, drawingh
    float ThisStartY;                                                                               //The start y of the current letter, drawingh
    float ThisEndX;                                                                                 //The end x of the current letter, drawing
    float ThisEndY;                                                                                 //The end y of the current letter, drawing
    int LetterNum;                                                                                  //Letter number in the loaded font
    int ThisLetter;                                                                                 //The current letter

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MapResource;                                                           //Map resource
    VertexPos* ThisSprite;                                                                          //Vertecies of the current sprite, drawing
//VAR

//Clamping string, if too long
if(StringLenth > LETTERS_NUM)
{
    StringLenth = LETTERS_NUM;
}

//Mapping resource
D3DResult = _DeviceContext -> Map(_vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MapResource);
if(FAILED(D3DResult))
{
    throw("Failed to map resource");
}
ThisSprite = (VertexPos*)MapResource.pData;

for(i = 0; i < StringLenth; i++)
{
    //Creating geometry for the letter sprite
    ThisStartX = StartX + ScreenCharWidth * static_cast<float>(i);
    ThisStartY = StartY;
    ThisEndX = ThisStartX + ScreenCharWidth;
    ThisEndY = StartY + ScreenCharHeight;

    ThisSprite[0].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisEndX, ThisEndY, 1.0f);
    ThisSprite[1].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisEndX, ThisStartY, 1.0f);
    ThisSprite[2].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisStartX, ThisStartY, 1.0f);

    ThisSprite[3].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisStartX, ThisStartY, 1.0f);
    ThisSprite[4].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisStartX, ThisEndY, 1.0f);
    ThisSprite[5].Position = XMFLOAT3(ThisEndX, ThisEndY, 1.0f);

    ThisLetter = static_cast<char>(StringToDraw[i]);

    //Defining the letter place(number) in the font
    if(ThisLetter < IndexA || ThisLetter > IndexZ)
    {
        //Invalid character, the last character in the font, loaded
        LetterNum = IndexZ - IndexA + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        LetterNum = ThisLetter - IndexA;
    }

    //Unwraping texture on the geometry
    ThisStartX = TexelCharWidth * static_cast<float>(LetterNum);
    ThisStartY = 0.0f;
    ThisEndY = 1.0f;
    ThisEndX = ThisStartX + TexelCharWidth;

    ThisSprite[0].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisEndX, ThisEndY);
    ThisSprite[1].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisEndX, ThisStartY);
    ThisSprite[2].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisStartX, ThisStartY);

    ThisSprite[3].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisStartX, ThisStartY); 
    ThisSprite[4].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisStartX, ThisEndY);   
    ThisSprite[5].TextureCoords = XMFLOAT2(ThisEndX, ThisEndY);

    ThisSprite += VERTEX_IN_RECT_NUM;
}

for(i = 0; i < StringLenth; i++, ThisSprite -= VERTEX_IN_RECT_NUM);

_DeviceContext -> Unmap(_vertexBuffer, 0);
_DeviceContext -> Draw(VERTEX_IN_RECT_NUM * StringLenth, 0);

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the piece of code constructing the Vertex Array seems correct to me at first glance, it seems like you are trying to Draw your vertices with a Shader which has not been set yet !
It is difficult to precisely answer you without looking at the whole code, but I can guess that you will need to do something like that :

1) Create Vertex and Pixel Shaders by compiling them first from their respective buffers

2) Create the `Input Layout` description, which describes the Input Buffers that will be read by the Input Assembler stage. It will have to match your `VertexPos` structure and your shader structure.

3) Set the Shader parameters.

4) Only now you can Set Shader rendering parameters : Set the `InputLayout`, as well as the Vertex and Pixel Shaders that will be used to render your triangles by something like :

```
_DeviceContext -> Unmap(_vertexBuffer, 0);

_DeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(myInputLayout);
_DeviceContext->VSSetShader(myVertexShader, NULL, 0); // Set Vertex shader
_DeviceContext->PSSetShader(myPixelShader, NULL, 0); // Set Pixel shader

_DeviceContext -> Draw(VERTEX_IN_RECT_NUM * StringLenth, 0);
```

This link should help you achieve what you want to do : http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut12.html

Also, I recommend you to set an `IndexBuffer` and to use the method `DrawIndexed` to render your triangles for performance reasons : It will allow the graphics adapter to store vertices in a vertex cache, allowing recently-used vertex to be fetched from the cache instead of reading it from the vertex buffer.
More about this concern can be found on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147325(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps!

P.S : Also, don't forget to release the resources after using them by calling `Release()`.